# Looking for optimal heuristic, A* search, pacman

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

[image: small board]

[image: larger board]

(all boards start with dots in every corner)

If i have a pacman board as such

```
*--------------------*
----------------------
----------------------
----------------------
----------------------
----------------------
----------------------
P--------------------*
----------------------
```

What would be the best heuristic to get him to eat all of the dots (`*`)? 
I am using an A* search. I have tried using manhattan distance, but once walls are thrown into the mix it does not achieve the same result as BFS, and is therefore not optimal. I'm looking for it to be optimal while expanding fewer nodes then BFS.

Comment: This is just an example lf the travelling salesman problem. There are several algorithms and heuristics for that. Finding the distance between two dots, resp. pacman and dots, can be done using some kind of flood fill algorithm.

Comment: I have looked into the traveling salesman problem and the common theme is to just use the manhattan distance. Also, I believe BFS is a flood fill algorithm.

Comment: Yes, BFS and flood fill mean the same thing in this context. Anyway, the main problem is finding the optimal order for the dots to eat. Finding the distance resp. the shortest path between the dots is relatively easy.

Comment: @ammoQ I see what you mean now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution:

(max(x,y) distance to the farthest corner

childXY = state[0]
    cornersLeft = state[1]

```
maxDistance = 10000
minDistance = 0
farthestCorner = 0
nearestCorner = 0


for corner in cornersLeft:

    if util.manhattanDistance(childXY, corner) > minDistance:
        minDistance = util.manhattanDistance(childXY, corner)  
        farthestCorner = minDistance - min((childXY[0]-corner[0]),(childXY[1]-corner[1]))


heuristic = farthestCorner

print "heuristic is: ", heuristic
return heuristic
```

There was a problem with my A* search that ultimately led to the main issue of my heuristic not working.